# Php preg_match_all search two strings with one pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a string like this:

```
{img:amp.jpg}
```

or like this:

```
{img:amp.jpg alt:something}
```

I'm using php function preg_match_all to get an image filename like "amp.jpg" or alt attribute like "something" at one time, but the alt attribute is optional. The problem is how to use one pattern to search filename and alt attribute if is set.

Finally i want to build an html image tag like:

```
<img src="amp.jpg" alt="something">
```

Comment: Please give us the code you have tried

Answer (score 1):

This creates the tag. When `alt` is not set it's empty in the tag.

```
$re = '/{img:(.*?)(?:}| alt:(.*?)})/';
$str = '{img:amp.jpg alt:something}';
$subst = '<img src="$1" alt="$2" />';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str, 1);
```

See https://regex101.com/r/IaPf6Y/2

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative without a regex you could:

- Remove and remove characters like `{` and `}` and replace `:` by `:=` and `img` with `src`
- Use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) with a whitespace as separator to create an array
- Add a double quote at the end of every item in the array using [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)
- Write the array back to a string using [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) with a whitespace as a separator.

This way, if there is no `alt` attribute then it will not be displayed and you can add more attributes if you want.

```
$str = "{img:amp.jpg alt:something}";
$str = str_replace(['{', '}', ':', 'img'], ['', '', '="', 'src'], $str);
$str =  sprintf(
    '<img %s>',
    implode(" ", array_map(function($a){return $a . '"';}, explode(' ', $str)))
);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/BCLNX)